# Passing DOM object dynamically in jQuery.animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using jQuery .animate method to animate a stack of cards. 
Assuming these are the four cards visually displayed `[#card1][#card2][#card3][#card4][#card5]`

Their div tags , `#card1` , `#card2`, `#card3` , `#card4` are stored in an array `cardStack()`
Now i want to animate each of these on click, one after the other when you click them.
So can i do something like

```
while(cardStack[0]!="undefined"){
    $('#cardStack[0]').click(function() {    
    $('#cardStack[0]').animate({"left": "+=130px","z-index": "1",queue:false},500);
});
i--;
}
```

is this possible ?

Comment: Like you click the left one and they all animate one after the other, or you click the left one and only the left one animates?

Comment: Do you have jquery objects stored in your array? or just the ids?

Comment: @AlienWebguy : I click the left most and it slides out left, then i click the next exposed card and it slides out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll annotate the source, so that you could actually learn something:

Save the reference to the array of cards.

```
var cards = $('#cards div');
```

The first flipped card will be outside our array.

```
var flippedIndex = cards.length;
```

Next, we create an array (with the same length as the `cards` array), containing information on which cards are flipped.

```
var flipped = new Array(flippedIndex);
```

The `flip` function animates and changes the class attribute of a card.

```
var flip = function (card, toggle) {
    card.slideUp(function () {
        card.toggleClass('back', toggle)
            .slideDown();
    });
};
```

Now we set the click listener.

```
cards.click(function () {
    var card = $(this),
```

`.index()` (http://api.jquery.com/index/) gives you the position of the card from left to right.

```
    index = card.index();
```

Lookup our `flipped` array to see if the card is flipped and check that it's the last card flipped.

```
if (!flipped[index] && index + 1 === flippedIndex) {
        flippedIndex = index;
```

Here we flip the card.

```
    flip(card, (flipped[index] = true));
} else if (flipped[index] && index === flippedIndex) {
    flippedIndex++;
```

Here we unflip it.

```
       flip(card, (flipped[index] = false));
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with the above is, i can click the second  or third card also. I want the user to be able to click only the right most card. Sort of like in real life, you can slide out only the open card, one at a time.

Comment: Okay great, works pretty much as i want it to. Except i tried changing the flip() function to slide the card on the x-axis (towards the left). So i have an id of the card (#card123) and i am trying to use the .css() function in jQuery to increment the left property of the card. However that doesn't seem to work. 

    `$(this).css("left", "+=50")`

Comment: Also, sorry if i forgot to mention - but the way i am displaying the cards is , they each have an id and they are positioned absolute. Not the best way i guess - but that what i have. 

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U32qt/5/ -- here, the cards are moving to the right. I'm afraid the rest you should try and do yourself. G'luck.